# Setting beamer title page template produces empty title page

Tags: beamer

I'm working on a beamer theme in which the title page should have the graphic on top. By reading `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` I thought I could accomplish this by setting the `title page` template.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\subtitle{Ut molestie eros sed enim}
\author{Aspasius Protus}
\date{June 26, 2023} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titlegraphic{graphic}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vbox{}
  \usebeamertemplate{titlegraphic}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \usebeamertemplate{title}
    \vskip1em\par
    \usebeamertemplate{author}
    \usebeamertemplate{institute}
    \usebeamertemplate{date}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The document compiles successfully with no errors or warnings, but the title page comes out blank. [Here is the log file](https://pastebin.com/yBjMAQtg).

I must be misunderstanding something about how `\setbeamertemplate` works without a predefined option. But what?

Comment: Can you show your .log file? This is the result I get with your mwe  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl3as.png

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That's strange. I tried Overleaf as well as my own machine (TeXShop on a mac). I can't paste the log into the question because it's too long, but I added a pastebin link.

Comment: Try with beamer v3.70, the `titlegraphic`, `title`, `author`, `institute` and `date` templates are new.

Comment: Aha, that sounds promising. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titlegraphic`, `title`, `author`, `institute` and `date` templates were recently added in https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/5a06df06cf88917234dfe86f7e06b064808fc618 . You will need at least beamer v3.70 to use these templates in your title page.

Alternatively you could define them yourself:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\subtitle{Ut molestie eros sed enim}
\author{Aspasius Protus}
\date{June 26, 2023} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titlegraphic{graphic}

\setbeamertemplate{title}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
      \vskip0.25em%
      {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
    \fi%     
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{author}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
    \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{institute}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
    \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{date}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{titlegraphic}{%
  {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \vbox{}
  \usebeamertemplate{titlegraphic}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \usebeamertemplate{title}
    \vskip1em\par
    \usebeamertemplate{author}
    \usebeamertemplate{institute}
    \usebeamertemplate{date}
  \endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm that updating my local version of beamer to 3.70 worked for me. This workaround is good for people (i.e., Overleaf users) who can't update their TeX-live unilaterally.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang You're welcome!